# get metadata about function with table.column%type-argument in postgres

Tags: postgresql, metadata

Is it possible to find out if an argument in a function in postgres was defined as

```
table.column%type foo
```

or

```
sometype foo
```

querying e.g. pg_proc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `proargtypes` column in `pg_proc` is an array of the types of all the function's arguments. Each type can then be cross-referenced to `pg_type.oid`.

So if I define a function like this:

```
steve@steve@[local] =# create function testfunc(pg_proc.proname%type) returns boolean language 'sql' immutable strict as $$ select true $$;
NOTICE:  type reference pg_proc.proname%TYPE converted to name
CREATE FUNCTION
```

Well, that notice isn't too hopeful.

The pg_proc entry for that function is:

```
 proname  | proargtypes
----------+-------------
 testfunc | 19
```

and type 19 is just "name". so it looks like the answer here is "no", I'm afraid.